# Copy data from one table to another with foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Copy exact same table data from one database to another database but table contains foreign key so both database two columns different values example : database 1 customer_id foreign key has 5 and customer name is John in customer table but database 2 customer_id of john is 1

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: insert into DBNEW.table1
select *
from DBOLD.table1 whren i run this query through "can not add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails" error

Comment: So make sure you have a 5 in the referenced table, also I don't see the relevance of mentioning john/1

Comment: Provide source and destination structure (including referencing/referenced tables) as CREATE TABLE and sample data as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table). Show desired final data state.

Comment: Both database contains customer table but john has different customerid in both db tables thats the issue i dont know how to insert customerid in dbnew.table1 column

Comment: This is the same John? How do you know that, John is a very common name? and which id do you want to keep?

Comment: Yes both john same. Everything same except customerid primary key (auto increment)
because combine both database now

Comment: i want to insert all column values same as olddb.table1 except customer_id . customer_id only insert from newdb.table1 based on olddb.table1 . please help me